# What is the notational convention for the single-qubit states $\lvert0\rangle\pm i\lvert1\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-state, terminology-and-notation

The features of major search engines (looking at you, google!) prevent me from searching for an answer to this question, so I will poll the community here.

Is the state $|{\pm} i\rangle$ generally understood to mean $|0\rangle \pm i|1\rangle$, in the same way that $|\pm\rangle$ is generally understood to mean $|0\rangle \pm |1\rangle$, or should I define it in the paper I'm writing ?

Comment: $\lvert L\rangle$ and $\lvert R\rangle$ are more commonly used to denote $\lvert0\rangle\pm i\lvert1\rangle$

Comment: @gIS: perhaps in your corner of the field --- I've never seen that notation before, though I have seen $\lvert \pm i \rangle$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ve never seen that notation, and would expect to see it defined. Personally, I use circles with clockwise/anti-clockwise arrows, trying to conjure up a visual connection with the idea of circular polarisation. But, again, I’d define it before usage.

Comment: Given the mixed nature of the response, I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think that most people would understand what you mean, although maybe mentioning they are the eigenstates of $Y$ wouldn't go amiss depending on your target audience.